# PFAnalytics as a remote logging and/or crash reporting facility

Tags: logging, parse-platform, crash-reports, testflight

Has anybody played around with the idea of using [PFAnalytics](http://www.parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFAnalytics.html) as a [remote logging](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) and [crash reporting](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1) solution? I'm currently beta testing my app using [TestFlight](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) and I can't get to crash reports without making my tester jump through hoops.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've used [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) and found it very easy to get crash reports both from beta testers and production users, without any extra effort on their part.

It isn't a logging utility, per se, and I could see using PFAnalytics for logging if you must, but the real answer is, what are you trying to do with capturing logs? PFAnalytics is great for analyzing how events occur over time.